# Dell Poweredge 1800 hangs on bios screen

Tags: dell-poweredge

I recently inherited a Dell Poweredge 1800 server and I'm trying currently to get it working. It's been offline for over a year now and I've no idea what might have been/what is wrong. I tried booting it and it hangs during the bios screen. The progress bar stops at about 4% (bad estimate) and the light on front begins flashing orange.

Any ideas what could be happening? I don't know what the light diagram, beep codes, or buttons on the server signify. I know next to nothing about it, so I'm lost here. I've been searching but Dell's not that great at disseminating server manuals.

Also, are there any service manuals, diagrams, beep code references, or light/button diagrams out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled "Dell Poweredge 1800 manual" and found this page:http://www.dell.com/support/Manuals/us/en/19/product/poweredge-1800

In the [Installation and Troubleshooting guide](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-1800_user%27s%20guide6_en-us.pdf) (linked from that page) there's a section on beep codes.

Should be enough to get you started.  It's probably bad RAM, though.  Might be worth starting by reseating it.

Answer (score 2):

If it had no memory in it when you received it, it more than likely requires ECC memory.

Also, if it's been sitting that long, pull the bios battery and replace it.

Sometimes the drive subsystem card has a memory board on it. Try removing and reseating that as well.